# Make WordPress search for only this tags or exclude certain tags from search

Tags: functions, search, tags

Is there something like a function for letting the WP search form search for ONLY some tags you fill in.
in example:

```
function wordpress_search{
    //search for tagname1, tagname2, tagname3
}
```

If that is not possible, will it be possible to do the opposite?
So to exclude tags from search?

I have no idea where to begin and google only points me to plugins where you have to (un)check a checkbox in every article

Comment: Oke, it says this post is a duplicate, but can someone give me a link to the other post?

Answer (score 0):

You dan do this in the [pre_get_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) hook. You can find a few examples on that page too :)